# Modifying and Deleting Items in asp gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I am currently working with gridview of asp.net.

I am using a SELECT statement to fill the gridview. When I am editing and deleting using in the gridview, It doesn't work, and all the example of this needs to pre-defined the columns of the gridvew meaning that there will be no SELECT statement to fill the gridview.

Is there a way that I can edit and delete the items in the gridview even though I use SELECT statement to fill the gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to modify the contents of the gridview cells:

```
Dim gvRow As GridViewRow

For Each gvRow In GridView1.Rows
  gvRow.Cells(rownumber).Text = "this was modified"
  next gvRow
```

You can use `GridView.DeleteRow` to remove a row.